# Ensure User from multiple domain for user that has never access to sharepoint

Tags: impersonation, spuser, ldap

This is my situation. I have a farm in which an instance of Sharepoint Foundation is installed.. Windows Server is configure to accept users from 3 trusted domain (xxx, yyy and zzz)

Suppose i have user like:

xxx\u1 yyy\u1

When i told people picker xxx\u1 he cannot resolve the name and ask me to choose between xxx\u1 and yyy\u1...

This is not a problem in that moment, but when I try to access programmatically to users it creates problem..

I access like this:

```
 Web.EnsureUser("xxx\u1");
```

Is there any other way to do the same thing but with the correct domain\username selection?

Powershell can't see the user

People Picker can't see the user but can suggest it

If i had the user with people picker suggestion Ensure User works (even if i remove it)..
So.. how can i let Sharepoint know of all my items? There is another way to do what Sharepoint's people picker does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a "non-sharepoint-problem". The other company (who said trust was ON) just give a wrong information.

The activation of the full bidirectional trust make everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've already asked this question:

Please see [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/get-single-user-from-multiple-domain-problem/30927#30927)

[Get single user from multiple domain problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/get-single-user-from-multiple-domain-problem/30927#30927)

Comment: I change some details on the question, asking a way to do programmatically the LDAP calls (or whatever happens) when using people picker.. For this reason i suppose i need a new question =)